# Changing user password in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to change a users password and it successfully changes but it doesn't let me do anything afterwards because the user becomes unauthorized... I'm probably missing a piece that reauthenticates them.

This is my code to update their password

```
def password

    if current_user.valid_password?(params[:current_password])

      current_user.password = params[:new_password]

      if current_user.save
        #sign them in

         #tried doing this to sign them in again but didn't work
          sign_in(:user, current_user)
          response.headers['X-CSRF-Token'] = form_authenticity_token
          response.headers['X-Pyne-Auth'] = current_user.authentication_token

          render :json => {:success => true} and return
        else
          render :json => {:success => false, error: "Unexpected error while trying to save user. Please try again."} and return
      end

    else
      render :json => {:success => false, error: "Your current password is incorrect. Please try again"} and return
    end

  end
```

I can update the password but have trouble accessing the app again because the user becomes unauthorized.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try `bypass_sign_in(@user)` as suggested [in the Devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password).

Comment: I'm going everything exactly as in that wiki and it doesn't go into here if `@user.update(user_params)` ... just goes into the else @Brian

Comment: Sounds like the `update` is failing then. Is there anything on your console that suggests what is preventing the update? Alternately, you could look at `@user.errors.full_messages` in the else clause and see what's going on.

Comment: Brian, I was doing that in my users controller and I just noticed I have this in my routes `devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => "api/v1/sessions", passwords: 'api/v1/passwords'}, :path_prefix => 'api/v1'` Does this mean I should have it in one of those controllers or something?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your view, but I suspect the users controller is the right place since you're not specifying a registrations controller.

Comment: I don't have a view. I'm calling these endpoints from an IOS application. Brian, does devise automatically make endpoints to edit a users password? I did rake routes and see this  `new_user_password GET    /api/v1/users/password/new(.:format)           api/v1/passwords#new
         edit_user_password GET    /api/v1/users/password/edit(.:format)          api/v1/passwords#edit`